# Struct that contains an alias to the first convertible type of a variadic pack

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have `typename T1` and I have a parameter pack `typename... Variadic`.

I want to create a struct that contains a using alias `using Type = ...` to the first type in the parameter pack that `T1` can be converted into. So far I have tried the following:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Variadic>
struct VariadicConvertibleType
{
    using Type = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value, T2>::type;
};
```

This could be a potential solution using SFINAE for the first two types, but I need to expand this to all the types in the pack using recursion. All my attempts failed so far, because you can't put conditionals into using alias declarations. Otherwise something similar to this could be used:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Variadic>
struct VariadicConvertibleType
{
    using Type = std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value ? T2 : VariadicConvertibleType<T1, Variadic...>::Type;
};
```

I can use everything up to (and including) C++14 to implement the solution. I can not using anything other than the standary library though.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional maybe? And what should be the base case for no compatible types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), like this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Variadic>
struct VariadicConvertibleType
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value, T2, typename VariadicConvertibleType<T1, Variadic...>::type>;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct VariadicConvertibleType<T1, T2>
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value);
    using type = T2;


    // Alternative base-case
    // using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value, T2, T1>;
};
```

I have provided two base-cases (alternative one in comment).
The primary one (which I thing is what you want) uses a (C++14) `static_assert` if `T1` is not convertible to any of the types in `Variadic`. The alternative base-case sets `type` to `T1` in that case.

**Test**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    using my_type_1 = typename VariadicConvertibleType<int, double, float>::type;
    std::cout << typeid(my_type_1).name() << '\n'; // double

    using my_type_2 = typename VariadicConvertibleType<int, int*, float>::type;
    std::cout << typeid(my_type_2).name() << '\n'; // float

    using my_type_3 = typename VariadicConvertibleType<int, int*, float*>::type;
    std::cout << typeid(my_type_3).name() << '\n'; // Complile error with the primary base-case, and int with the alternative base-case.
}
```

Comment: The `static_assert` solution does not seem to be working for me, but the alternative base-case one does. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `std::conditional` is that it requires both the types you feed it to be well defined. To circumvent that, you need to introduce a kind of indirection in the process.

To do so, we will have a helper template that given a boolean, will either define the type or fall back on the next element.

```
namespace details {

template <bool B, typename T, typename... Args>
struct FirstConvertibleImpl;

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct FirstConvertibleImpl<true, T, U, Args...> {
    using type = U;
};

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename... Args>
struct FirstConvertibleImpl<false, T, U, V, Args...> {
    using type = typename FirstConvertibleImpl<std::is_convertible<T, V>::value, T, V, Args...>::type;
};

}
```

If the given types do not lead to a valid conversion, this will obviously issue an error as we didn't care to define "invalid" cases (`FirstConvertibleImpl<false, T1, T2>` has no implementation for any types `T1, T2`)

Now we make a higher level interface for a clearer use:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct FirstConvertibleInPack;

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct FirstConvertibleInPack<T, U, Args...> {
    using type = typename details::FirstConvertibleImpl<std::is_convertible<T, U>::value, T, U, Args...>::type;
};
```

Again, we do not care to define the cases where `Args... = []` because these cases are ill-formed anyway.

A [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25735a596a98392d) can be found on Coliru.

You can of course abstract that even deeper and make this example more generic by allowing to apply any binary traits you fancy.